# How to pass values from from to sql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to php programming. I'm kind of confused and I can't find any helpful information online. I'm trying to build a school manangement system from scratch. What I need is to get all the 'offered courses' from the database and put it in a form and allow the student to add the classes directly from the row. How can I do that?

I created a form and an input where the student might enter the course number and register for class. And it works fine. But I feel like it's not practical.

Here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
// include("config.php");
include("functions.php");
// $sql="SELECT `course_num`, `professors`.`name` AS pName, `courses`.`name`AS cName , max_students FROM `courses`, `student_courses`,`professors` WHERE `professors`.`id`=`courses`.`professor_teaching` AND `student_id`= '".$_SESSION['student_id']."'";
// $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$result = viewAllCourses();
?>
<form method="post" action="functions.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><label>Course No.</label></th>
        <th><label>Course Name</label></th>
        <th><label>Professor</label></th>
        <th><label>Max. Students</label></th>
        <th><label>Action</label></th>      
    </tr>
<?php 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
?>
    <tr>
        <td><label name="course_num"><?php echo $row['course_num'];?>
            <input type="hidden" name ="coursenumber" value=<?php $row['course_num']?>>
        </label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['cName'];?></label>
        </td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['pName']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['max_students']; ?></label></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="add"></td>
    </tr>

    </form>
    </table>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

and then in the `functions.php` I have this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $link = conn();
    echo "TST";
    exit;
    $courseNum= $_POST['coursenumber'];

    $record = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `student_courses`
                        (`student_id`, `course_id_num`) 
                VALUES ('".$_SESSION['student_id']."', '$courseNum')");
}
```

But it does nothing.

I tried adding an input tag for the course_number and passing it from there. But  it doesn't work. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Try removing the `exit;` from that bit of `functions.php` That will kill the script dead hence its doing nothing

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You start with `<form><table>`, but you end with `</form></table>`. The end tags have to be the reverse of the start tags, `</table></form>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added it as a test! but it is not even printing it!

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for letting me know about this error! but it is still not working ..

Comment: Lots of little errors: Your form says use POST `method="post"` but `functions.php` is looking at `$_GET`. It should be looking at `$_POST`

Comment: @Dharman Ok, seen it and fixed it THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're the same names for the inputs in all the rows. When you submit the form, `$_POST['coursenumber']` will just be the last course number in the table, not the one the user clicked on. You can put the course number in the value of the `add` button, rather than a hidden input. When a form has multiple submit buttons, the value comes from the one that was clicked.

You need to fix the order of the `</form>` and `</table>` tags, so they nest properly.

```
<?php 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
?>
    <tr>
        <td><label name="course_num"><?php echo $row['course_num'];?>
        </label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['cName'];?></label>
        </td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['pName']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['max_students']; ?></label></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="<?php echo $row['course_num'];?>"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Also, since you're submitting the form with `method="POST"`, the button will be `$_POST['add']`, not `$_GET['add']`.

You should use a prepared statement to protect against SQL-injection.

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $link = conn();
    $courseNum= $_POST['add'];
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare("INSERT INTO student_courses (student_id, course_id_num) VALUES (?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $_SESSION['student_id'], $courseNum);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

If you want to pass multiple fields, you can put a separate form with multiple hidden inputs into each row, rather than making the whole table a form.

```
<?php 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
?>
    <tr>
        <td><label name="course_num"><?php echo $row['course_num'];?>
        </label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['cName'];?></label>
        </td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['pName']; ?></label></td>
        <td><label><?php echo $row['max_students']; ?></label></td>
        <td><form action="functions.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="coursenumber" value="<?php echo $row['course_num'];?>">
            <niput type="hidden" name="something" value="<?php echo $row['something'];?>">
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="add">
        </form></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Then the `functions.php` script can use `$_POST['course_num']` and `$_POST['something']` to get these parameters.

Comment: A bit of unrelated question to this post, but can I pass more than one value in the value of 'add'?

Comment: You could do something like `<?php echo $var1 . "-" $var2;?>` and then use `explode("-", $_POST['add'])` to split it up.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I just noticed that the value of the button now is the course_number in your proposed solution! Any way to change that?

Comment: You can change it to whatever you want. But isn't that what you want to insert into the table?

Comment: I've added another example showing how you can send multiple input fields.

Comment: Thank you! I highly appreciate it!